# Error: Cannot access a disposed object Xamarin.Forms

Tags: object, xamarin

How can I catch which object is disposed from Xamarin.Forms app. The problem occurs when I am navigating between pages more specific on `PopAsync()`, But my question is in general how to catch which one is the disposed object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the disposed object should be part of the `Exception`'s stack trace. Try to dive into the exception message or inner exception to see if it is there.

In addition you could go to **Debug** -> **Windows** -> **Exception Settings**, search for `System.ObjectDisposedException` and check the checkbox next to it to make debugger stop when it encounters this exception.